# Linux DB2 server exhibit extreme load

Tags: linux, load, db2, average, iostat

We have a DB2 Server running on a SLES 11 server (novell) on x64 and every once in a while it will exhibit extreme load... and by extreme im mostly being conservative.

This server has 256GB or RAM and 8 cpu cores ( 4x2 cores cpu) and today it peaked
at... better sit down here... 1154 of Load Average.

I know the CPU is not running out of steam because on other normal servers if we get like 40+ Load Average the server become unresponsive even to Network connexion (ssh)

But this server will still accept ssh and top doesn't lag too much.

I've checked the iostats to see if some disks are getting way behind but yet the worst I have on my many many disks is: 360.00 of await and my cpu %iowait is 2.26

So... where does this LOAD come from ?!?!

Does anyone have any idea?!

Comment: It would help if you posted the version of DB2 that you are using, and perhaps some screenshots.

Comment: Also, this probably belongs on ServerFault

Comment: DB2 is version 9.7 but im not sure if it really DB2's fault thats what I would like to determine.. who's fault is it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about in DB2.. but in linux, load is just how many processes are running or waiting to run. Somewhere, someplace, you must have like 1146 processes waiting to run (and 8 running).

Comment: Not quite that simple actually.. The Load is a mix of processes that are waiting on something it can be storage IO, network IO, CPU io.. and probably other things. So no its not quite as simple has you have more process than the number of CPU.

Comment: But the point remains.. you have a bunch of stuff running or waiting to run. Find out what said stuff is.